# Existence of an object in many-to-many relation

Tags: django, django-models, model, many-to-many

Python Django code:

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __contains__(user):
        pass # What should be here?
```

(`User` here is another model.)

How to efficiently check whether a user "belongs" to the given group of users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it by m2m manager:

```
def __contains__(self, user):
    return user in self.users.all() # return boolean
```

Now just check it with your instances:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=some_pk) 
group = UserGroup.objects.get(pk=some_pk)
# or use another queries to fetch instanses
if user in group:
    # do your logic
```